How do compilers use the strict aliasing rule to make optimizations
An article called The joys and perils of C and C++ aliasing, Part 1 offers this example:
int foo(int *a, long *b)
{
    int t = *a;
    *b = 0;          // cannot change *a
    return *a - t;   // can be folded to zero
}

With the commentary:

Because a and b are declared to be pointers to incompatible types, and because C and C++ require that objects have their stored value accessed only by an lvalue of a compatible type, the store to *b cannot affect the value of *a cached in the variable t, which is typically a register. Therefore, the operands in the subtraction expression must be equal, and the result must be zero.

But in Part 2, we see a similar example:
int bar(int *a, long *b)
{
    int t = *a;
    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof *b; ++i)
    ((unsigned char*)b)[i] = 0;
    
    return *a - t;   // must not be folded
}

where folding is not possible:

In this case, the compiler cannot fold the return expression because the function would be valid if called with b equal to a. However, using restrict when declaring the a and b pointers would make calling f with overlapping objects invalid. Doing that would re-enable the optimization opportunity.

I understand that an unsigned char * can be used for aliasing the same way that a char * could. But my understanding is that a and b already signal that they will not alias in both signatures, because one is a int * and one is a long *.
My mental model is that the function's argument types are subject to strict aliasing rules, so that when either...

a and b occupy overlapping memory (e.g. via reinterpret_cast) and we're in UB territory
a and b have non-overlapping representations in memory

...type-aware optimizations (e.g. folding of return statement) can still be applied. I assume this applies equally for foo and bar.
Why does the use of type punning inside of bar change whether the compiler can fold the *a - t expression?

That must be an issue in the article itself. In its example with *b = 0;, a is never referenced through b and b is never referenced through a, so there is no aliasing issue at all. If the intent is you shouldn't reference a through b and vice-versa, that's just a statement of the strict aliasing rule itself. long and int are not compatible types. The value of *a isn't magically cached in t, t is simply a local variable to the function to which the value stored at the address held by a is assigned. The paragraph isn't clear, don't read too much into it.

C++ has three special types that are allowed to violate the strict aliasing rules:  char*, unsigned char*, and std::byte*.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing (that's C++; C rules are different)

Note that the linked question explains it for C. C++ has slightly stricter rules; only allowing signed/unsigned variants, the type itself, and bye + char + unsigned char. Not signed char or unions

The rule at issue is C23 Standard - 6.5 (6)(7) which has been the discussed many times on this site. The C++ equivalent is in [basic.lval]

@DavidC.Rankin The point is that the aliasing rule guarantees the compiler that a and b can't represent the same address, which would otherwise be allowed. So then the compiler knows that writing to *b won't change the value of *a. So the compiler can optimize away a second load of *a and then constant fold the result to 0.

I don't really see that as possible where you have distinct parameters of two separate types. The only way to get there would be to cast one or the other to (void*) in C or static_cast in C++ to intentionally mask the type difference -- which doesn't seem to make a good example. The discussion in the following paragraph on restrict seems more applicable there.

@DavidC.Rankin It is reinterpret_cast in C++. I'll admit to not really reading the article. If this is just a demonstration of how the aliasing rule will impact optimization, then it seems a decent example to me, because the compiler must produce valid code that also works in these edge cases. Of course I agree that the code itself is bad if used under the assumption that it should actually work with intentionally mistyped pointers.

Although the article does say "It seems reasonable to expect a compiler to report a violation of this requirement upon detecting one." which I do not agree with. It would probably result in a flood of useless warning messages for a common optimizer action, while one would have to intentionally cast objects to wrong types for it to matter at all. If someone writes code that intentionally uses mistyped pointers to  objects, the code should be compiled with -fno-strict-aliasing to begin with.

It's kind of funny how many different ways we can invent to explain the rule of "don't access the value of an object through a pointer of a different type". Then add a few exceptions for byte-sized access and now bit-casts in C++ and have it proliferate into an endless morass of articles and blogs that usually confuse the matter further. I've long thought the text of 6.5 in C was one of the most awkwardly written sections of the standard. C++ sprinkles the pain over a wider area in the standard to prevent the shock all at once...

Btw @nhnl: As the comment above mentions the C++ standard implements the aliasing rule differently from the C standard and there are different results as well. the C++ standard has incorporated it much more deeply in the whole object model. The article however uses only the C terminology. For example "compatible types" do not exist in C++. Nor does "effective type" exist in C++ and it is wrong that the last store would determine the C++-equivalent of the effective type (but I think that is also generally wrong in C as well), etc.

But as also mentioned before, it is pretty simple in practice: Do not intentionally mistype your pointers (which is easy to not do accidentally especially in modern-style C++ if you forbid C-style casts and reinterpret_cast) and you won't have any problems with your code. If you do, then compile with -fno-strict-aliasing instead of trying to inspect and trick the optimizer to do specific things you want.

@user17732522 tried clarifying question in edit

@nhnl You have causality in your edit the wrong way around: In foo, if a and b overlap, then the program has UB according to the language rules. In bar that is not the case as explained in my answer. That's just how the language is specified. Because foo would have UB if a and b overlap, the compiler is allowed to assume that the second load from a will produce the same value as the first load from a. That way the correctness of non-UB programs is not affected and only the UB scenario produces a result that differs from non-application of the optimization.

Compilers and optimizations do not cause undefined behavior. The language rules specify whether or not a program execution has undefined behavior. Because certain operations have undefined behavior, the compiler is permitted to apply additional, otherwise invalid, optimizations. Optimization can not change the observable behavior of a program execution with defined behavior (outside the range of unspecified behaviors).

Also remember that the compiler generally doesn't know whether or not a and b overlap in calls to the functions. The function is compiled in one translation unit and called potentially in any other translation unit where a and b might overlap. The optimization can only be applied if the compiler knows that a and b will not overlap in any call. The way it knows that in foo is because if there was a call with overlap, the program would have UB and then the compiler doesn't have to care about this case. A program with UB is permitted to produce any outcome.

@user17732522 That's a helpful explanation, thank you. I'm also slightly surprised by the implications. Am I understanding correctly that once a compiler sees a char* (or other byte addressed type), it pessimistically assumes any memory that can be dereferenced in the same scope must be reloaded?

@nhnl Yes, if the origin of the pointers lies outside the available context, e.g. because it is a function parameter and the function isn't inlined. If it can see where the pointer points, then it may still be able to deduce that there is no aliasing. I think that, even if the article doesn't seem to focus on that, the important take-away aside from "do not mistype your pointers" is that using char, unsigned char or std::byte instead of other types can negatively impact performance because the compiler has to consider these edge cases. (It applies only to these three types btw.)

As the article also explains, C has the restrict keyword which can be used on function parameters to explicitly tell the compiler that they do not alias, regardless of how they are used in the function and regardless of types. C++ doesn't have any equivalent for that, but compilers typically support restrict (maybe with a different spelling) also in C++ modes.

The type aliasing rule has a specific exception for accessing an object of any type through a glvalue of type unsigned char (as well as char and std::byte). For these types and only these type there is no undefined behavior under the aliasing rule that the compiler could exploit for optimization. C has similar exceptions to the aliasing rule, but it is specified differently in terms of the object model.
If a and b represent the same address, then either *b = 0 or int t = *a; must have undefined behavior because there can only either be an int or a long object alive at that address and only that one can be accessed. The other access would either attempt to access an out-of-lifetime object or attempt to access an object of one type through a glvalue of a different type, violating the type aliasing rule. One or the other would have to cause undefined behavior and the compiler can therefore assume that this situation, i.e. that a and b represent the same address, can't happen. (Neither can the memory ranges for the int and long objects pointed to overlap for that matter, because an int object and a long object can't both be alive in overlapping storage at the same time.)
In the second example *b = 0 is replaced by ((unsigned char*)b)[i] = 0. The pointer b is never accessed as long type, only as unsigned char. Because of the exception mentioned above, this is not UB per the aliasing rules, if a and b both point to the same object of type int that is the (only) object alive at the address they both represent. Therefore the compiler cannot assume that a and b represent different addresses.
That being said, the C++ standard lacks any actual definition of how the access through the unsigned char glvalue or the pointer arithmetic on the unsigned char* pointer should behave, so that reading the standard pedantically it is still UB regardless.
However, the usual assumption is that it should behave as if the unsigned char* pointer result of the cast was a pointer into the object representation of the original object, considered as an array of unsigned char. This still leaves a lot of things unclear in alot of edge cases, but explains how the common usage usually works as intended.
With that understanding ((unsigned char*)b)[i] = 0 would directly modify the object representation of the int object that a points to in the valid scenario mentioned above. Changing the object representation of the int object means changing its value and therefore the compiler cannot assume that the latter read of *a will produce the same value as the one before the write and must instead reload it again.


In foo, the assignment *b = 0 does not affect *a because the types are incompatible under strict aliasing rules. This makes it safe for the compiler to fold *a - t to zero.
In bar, however, casting b to unsigned char* and writing byte-by-byte means the compiler must allow for the possibility that *a was modified in the loop. Therefore, the value of *a - t cannot be assumed to be zero, and the compiler must avoid folding this expression.

The key difference is that unsigned char* is a special type that bypasses strict aliasing rules, allowing the possibility of modifying the int object pointed to by a indirectly through b.
